# Simple LISP code won't catch input errors

Tags: recursion, error-handling, lisp, factorial

I am writing a very simple lisp code for the recursive factorial function. When called using a number, it works fine. However, when I try to call it using something that is not a number (ex. a) I get the following error:

Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable `A'.
  [condition type: UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

However, this is supposed to be caught in my code. Here is my code:

```
(defun FactorialRec (num)
   (cond                                                  
      ((not(numberp num))
         (princ "Argument must be a number.")
         (terpri)
         ())
      ((equal num 1) ;base case                                                       
         1)
      ((<= 1 num) (* num(FactorialRec (- num 1))))
   )
)
```

I do not know why the numberp is not catching this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Break 2 [6]> (FactorialRec "A")
Argument must be a number.
```

It works on my machine. So I think you were passing `A` but not `"A"`?

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting used to writing and running lisp that careless things like this happen. So, A can never be evaluated in lisp?

Comment: @amaliat21, I think Barmar had already introduced it very well :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix parameter type checking into your main logic. Use the `check-type` macro on entry into the function, or as early in the function as is convenient:

```
(defun factorial (num)
  (check-type num (and integer (satisfies plusp)))
  (if (= num 1)
     1
     (* (factorial (1- num)) num)))
```

The form `(and integer (satisfies plusp))` is a type expression. Lisp types can be joined with operators like `and`, and the `satisfies` type operator can be used to create a type out of any predicate function. So we can specify a type whose domain values are objects which are integers, and which are positive. `check-type` will happily validate our variable to see whether it belongs to this type.

Also I used the built-in `1-` function which subtracts one from its argument instead of `(- num 1)`.  This `1-` is a symbol, not special syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring before your function is ever being called. When you type a function call expression in the Lisp interpreter, it first evaluates all the arguments and the calls the function. If you use a variable that isn't bound, the argument evaluation fails.

Comment: Thank you! I have found my problem.